# Unable to download annotation attachment throwing Exception

Tags: dynamics-crm, file-permissions, dynamics-crm-online, workflow-activity, dynamics-365

I am creating a workflow activity to download the annotation attachment from a custom entity. Running the workflow throws

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here is my code:

```cs
private static string SaveFile(string fileName, string noteBody)
{
    string outputFileName = @"C:\temp\" + fileName;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(noteBody))
    {
         // Download the attachment in the current execution folder.
         byte[] fileContent = Convert.FromBase64String(noteBody);
         System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(outputFileName, fileContent);

    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("File content is empty or cannot be retrieved");
    }

    return outputFileName;
}
```

Debugging it shows that the error is thrown by:

```cs
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(outputFileName, fileContent);
```

From Visual Studio I get this exception

> Request for permission of type System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission

Answer (score 0):

CRM online plugins & workflows must be registered & run in sandbox isolation mode, which is secured & partially trusted in cloud (not Full trust).

Hence you cannot access `C:\temp\` in Server from Plugin/workflow code. You will get FileIOPermission exception.

> Developers have the option of registering their plug-ins in the sandbox, known as partial trust, or outside the sandbox, known as full trust. Full trust is supported for on-premises and Internet-facing Microsoft Dynamics 365 deployments. For a Microsoft Dynamics 365 (online) deployment, plug-ins or custom workflow activities must be registered in the sandbox (partial trust)
>
> Access to the file system, system event log, certain network protocols, registry, and more is prevented in the sandbox.

[Read more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx)